# Is the linear dual of a cyclic $K[G]$-module $K[G]$-cyclic

Tags: representation-theory, dual-spaces, free-modules

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $K$ be a field of characteristic $0$. Let $M$ be a free, finitely generated $K$-module and assume in addition that $M$ is cyclic as a (left) $K[G]$-module.

Consider the dual $M^{\ast}:=Hom_{K}(M, K)$ of $M$. I know that there is a non-canonical isomorphism of $K$-modules $M \cong M^{\ast}$ and that $M^{\ast}$ can be made into a $K[G]$-module.

Can we prove something about the structure of $M^{\ast}$ as a $K[G]$-module, for example can we prove that it is cyclic, since $M$ is cyclic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it’s cyclic.

A cyclic module $M$ is just one that is a quotient of $K[G]$, the regular $K[G]$-module. But by Maschke’s theorem, a quotient of $K[G]$ is a direct summand, so $M^*$ is a direct summand of $K[G]^*$, which is isomorphic to $K[G]$, so $M^*$ is also cyclic.

But in positive characteristic, where Maschke’s theorem doesn’t apply, it’s not always true that the dual of a cyclic module is cyclic.

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of the isomorphism between $K[G]^{\ast}$ and $K[G]$. Is the generator of $M^{\ast}$ as a $K[G]$-module the dual (under the non-canonical iso $M \cong M^{\ast}$ as $K$-modules) of the generator of $M$ as a $K[G]$-module? Can one extend this to when you have more than one generators?

Comment: @E.Blioch Yes, it extends to any finite number of generators: having $\leq k$ generators is equivalent to being a quotient, and hence a direct summand, of $K[G]^k$, so the dual is a summand, and hence a quotient, of $(K[G]^k)^*\cong K[G]^k$.

Comment: @E.Blioch I'm not sure what you mean by the question about the non-canonical iso. Since it's non-canonical, you could choose any isomorphism, which might send the generator of $M$ to the generator of $M^*$, but might not.

Comment: My bad, I meant to ask whether choosing generators for $M$ as a $K[G]$-module and then mapping them with respect to some isomorphism $M \cong M^{\ast}$ will give generators for $M^{\ast}$ as $K[G]$-modules. What you say means that we cannot really control this, i.e. it really depends what isomorphism $M \cong M^{\ast}$ we choose?

Comment: @E.Blioch Yes, exactly.